# Why does this line of code in SQL not work?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE id = (SELECT person_id FROM stars WHERE movie_id = (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE year = 2004))
ORDER BY birth;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Do you get an error or is the result not as expected? Also, which database are you using? (Oracle, Sql Server,...)

Comment: The output is only 1 name, it should me much more.

Comment: Please show what error/unexpected result you obtained. Describe your input data in minimized form, ideally as dbfiddle.

Comment: And, excuse me, but I don't know which database. Still a beginner

Comment: 145786 | Orlando Casín | 1947

Comment: The output is correct. It's just that it should be multiple records not one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could solve your problem by changing the `=` to `IN` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE id IN (SELECT person_id FROM stars WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE year = 2004))
ORDER BY birth;
```

An example of your table and data would be really helpful.

Hopefully i got your idea right!